Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container : driver failed programming exter listen tcp4 0: bind: address already in use
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container : driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint :(f102f1a4d9c7): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:54343: bind: address already in use
we are using docker-compose.yml file for stop/start the containers as it’s intermittent issue we see this error every time for different containers , we have updated docker/docker-compose version but issue still persist ,
